# Like vs Similar to vs rLike

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to understand the differences between **like**, **rlike** and **similar to** in postgres and whether there are specific use cases for each operator.

Being familiar with TSQL I generally used the **like** operator to do things like

```
Select * From Table where ColA like '%[0-9]%[a-z]%'
```

But in postgres the same statement would not yield the same results.

My questions are:

1. What, if any, operator in postgres (**like**, rlike, **similar to**, ...) most closely mimics the functionality/usability of the **like** operator in tsql?
2. Is there a general rule of thumb when deciding which operator to use in postgress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIKE does not support regular expression in SQL (and SQL Server's implementation isn't a real regex to begin with).

The `similar to` operator is probably the closest to SQL Server's LIKE as it supports the `%` wildcards from the "regular" LIKE operator but also allows to use a regex,

So

```
where cola similar to '%[0-9]%[a-z]%'
```

should return the same as in SQL Server with the exception that it's case sensitive while SQL Server is not by default.

If you want a real regex, then you need to use the `~` operator

```
Select * 
From Table 
where ColA ~ '[0-9].*[a-z]'
```

In a "real" regular expression the `%` is not a wildcard, so you need to use `.*` which matches zero or more characters. `~` automatically does a partial match so there is no need to "translate" the leading and trailing `%` from your expression.

If you want to use a case insensitive match, use  `~*` instead.